# My google scripts code does not update a cell (N5) thats keeps track of sales made

Tags: google-sheets-api

I've written a code on google scripts that should update a cell on a sheet if another cell is updated with the phrase "vendio" (sold in Spanish).  After it reads that "vendio" has been entered, it finds the price of the cell 4 rows over and adds it to the cell that is keeping track of total sales.

```
function TotalSales() {
   /*
  @OnlyCurrentDoc
  */
   //Get Current Google Sheet, Get Active Sheet Tab.
  //finds current active sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  //find current active cell 
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell();
  //find row number of active cell 
  var row = cell.getRow(); 

  //defines a variable to the cell adjacent to where "vendio" is 
  var H_cell = ss.getRange(row,8);
  //gets value of Column H cell adjacent to where "vendio" is 
  var H_value = H_cell.getValue();

  //find the range of N5 cell 
  var N5_cell = ss.getRange("N5");
  //Gets value inside N5 Range 
  var N5_value = N5_cell.getValue();

  if(cell.getValue() == "vendio") { //cell.getValue() gets value in the active cell

    sum_value = H_value + N5_value; // sums value of adjacent cell to vendio and value of an cell thats keeping count 

    N5_cell.setValue(sum_value); //sets N5 value to the sum of N5 and H(row)

  } else {
    N5_cell.setValue(N5_value);
  };

}

function onEdit(){ 
     TotalSales(); 
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I edited my code and changed the function onEdit to match the name of the function my code is running inside.  I've left it on here for anyone else to see.